# How can I create a slot on a Cylindrical object and assemble it?

Tags: solidworks

I used wrap feature to create the slot but when I try to assemble it (mechanical mate options > slot) I can not select the slot. Is there another way?

See the example. I want that pin to slide in that slot

[image: example]

Comment: I would try asking at https://forum.solidworks.com/

Answer (score 0):

I believe the slot mate only works for flat surfaces. I would do a path mate along a 3-d line that connects the foci of the slot. Then I would make the end of the pin tangent to the face of the slotted part.